# TypeError: $.ajax is not a function work fine in one page but not in another

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, web

I have a problem, while I am trying to use ajax function I am getting the following message: 
TypeError: $.ajax is not a function.

In the same project on another page AJAX function call work fine but in this page it doesn't work.

I am using in both pages with the same header

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang= "he">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/mainCSS.css">


<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body dir ="rtl">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id = "singUpBtn">singup</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id = "loginBtn" >Login</button>
<script>
$('#loginBtn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"registration.php",
        data:$('#regForm').serialize(),
        success:function(result){
                if(result == 1){
                window.location.assign("../Pages/page1.php");
                }else{
                    $('#regAlert').html(result).show();
                }
            }
        })  
})
$('#singUpBtn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"registration.php",
            data:$('#singUpForm').serialize(),
            success:function(result){
                if(result == 1){
                window.location.assign("../Pages/page1.php");
                }else{
                    $('#singUpAlert').html(result).show();
                }
            }
        })  
})  
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why on my other page page1.php the ajax call work fine but on my main page it doesn't.

what I am doing wrong?

I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: When does the error appear in your console? On page load, or after you click a button? If it's after you click a button, then that makes zero sense....

Comment: Is this the source from the page that fails? Or the code from the page that works?

Comment: You have an extra `})` on the end of all that script. (also missing a bunch of semicolons... but that generally works) I'm guessing the extra `})` was from a document.ready that is missing from your code example.

Comment: yes the extra }) is from document ready. and the code is from the page that doesn't work

Comment: the error appeared only after the button was clicked

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your ajax code with below if it could help you

```
<script>
$('#loginBtn').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"registration.php",
    data:$('#regForm').serialize(),
    success:function(result){
            if(result == 1){
            window.location.assign("../Pages/page1.php");
            }else{
                $('#regAlert').html(result).show();
            }
        }
    });  
});

$('#singUpBtn').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"registration.php",
        data:$('#singUpForm').serialize(),
        success:function(result){
            if(result == 1){
            window.location.assign("../Pages/page1.php");
            }else{
                $('#singUpAlert').html(result).show();
            }
        }
    }); 
});  

</script>
```